# Combinatorial proof of $\binom{n + 1}{2} - \binom{n}{2} = n$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

I need to prove that $\binom{n+1}{2} - \binom{n}{2} = n$

1- Is it enough to simplify the left side and arrive to the conclusion that it is equal to n? I did that and it is, or do we need to do a full mathematical induction / contradiction.

2 - I need to show that it does not work for any other number other than $2$ (in $r$). Is it enough find a counter example and prove that it is no true other than $2$ or do I need to do something else?

Thank you

Comment: Using mathematical induction will make the process tedious. Just the simplification does the job well. It is absolutely correct. But why do you need to show that it does not work for any other number.

Comment: For (1), what you did is okay. But for (2) just finding one counterexample is not enough because it only shows that the result does not hold true for that value of $r$. You need to show that for all $r > 2$, the result will not be true. Actually the result is true for $r=n$ as well.

Comment: Try to prove that $\binom{n+1}{r} - \binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{r-1}$. If you solve $\binom{n}{r-1} = n$, you get either $r = 2$ or $n-1$.

Comment: Simplifying the left hand side seems like the *long* way to do it. The straightforward combinatorial argument is much easier.

Comment: @user290335: you asked for a combinatorial proof but suggested an algebraic one!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a combinatorial proof:

A committee of two people is to be selected from a group of $n + 1$ people, one of whom is Amelia.  We wish to count the number of committees we can form if Amelia is one of the members.

Left hand side:  The number of ways a committee of two people that includes Amelia can be selected from a group of $n + 1$ people is the difference in the number of committees of two people that can be formed from the $n + 1$ available people and the number of committees of two people that can be formed without Amelia.

Right hand side:  The number of such committees is the number of ways of picking a partner for Amelia from one of the other $n$ people in the group.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do both points at once. Notice that

$$n = \binom{n+1}{k} - \binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{k-1}$$

This gives you possible solutions $k-1=1$ and $k-1=n-1$, or $k=2$ and $k=n$. The $2$ is then the only constant satisfying this identity independently on $n$.

Comment: I know that $\binom{n}{r}$=$\binom{n}{n-r}$ but I cannot understand how do I solve what you wrote and get k-1=1 and k-1=n-1,or k=2 and k=n. Can you please explain it better? thanks

Comment: This is based on the fact that $\binom{n}{0} = 1$, $\binom{n}{1}=n$ and that for $n-1>k>1$ you have $\binom{n}{k} > n$. This can be seen by checking first few values of $n$ and is not that hard to prove.

Comment: I have tried many options, but I think that if $ \binom{n+1}{1}-\binom{n}{r-1} = n $ I did a couple of examples and it is true since 5C1-4C0=4. Can you let me know if I am doing it right? Thanks 
 = 1

Comment: I am not sure how is this related to the original problem but since you have $\binom{n+1}{1} = n+1$ your equation is equivalent to $1 = \binom{n}{r-1}$. So this will not work for all values of $r$.